# How to execute command which requires input from user

Tags: go

I want to execute perforce command line "p4" from Go to do the login job. "p4 login" require user to input password.

How can I run a program that requires user's input in Go?

The following code doesn't work.

```
err  = exec.Command(p4cmd, "login").Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [os/exec.Command](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command) docs:

```
// Stdin specifies the process's standard input. If Stdin is
// nil, the process reads from the null device (os.DevNull).
Stdin io.Reader
```

Set the command's Stdin field before executing it.

Comment: Despite this being seven years old, some more context for this answer would be great.

Answer (score 8):

```
// To run any system commands. EX: Cloud Foundry CLI commands: `CF login`
cmd := exec.Command("cf", "login")

// Sets standard output to cmd.stdout writer
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout

// Sets standard input to cmd.stdin reader
cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin

cmd.Run()
```

Comment: @Anna i have added comments to above code. Does this help? Thanks