# How wrap a command that is interactive

Tags: go

I am building an ftp wrapper that does some stuff before I spawn, I could easily do it in a shell script but wondering how I could do it in go

While exec.Command works for simple commands.

```
out, err := exec.Command("ls").Output() // Works
```

How do I wrap commands that are interactive e.g., ftp

```
out, err := exec.Command("ftp").Output()
```

It just exits. How do I deal with stdin ?

e.g., bash equivalent :

```
> ./t.sh 
Welcome to myftp 

ftp> open blahblah.com

> cat t.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo "Welcome to myftp "
#extra commands such as auth/authoriz.. etc.,
shift
echo "$@"
ftp
```

c++ equivalent :

```
int main() {
    system("ftp");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you going to supply the `ftp` command with input?

Comment: The non interactive part is easy right ? just do  : if len(os.Args) > 1 {
  str = cmd + " " + strings.Join(os.Args[1:], " ")
 } else {
  str = cmd
 }

Comment: @Victor: You can't just concatenate command arguments in a single string unless you're going to have a shell lex them again. What exactly do you want to do with stdin? Are you supplying a stream, or are you trying connect it to a ptty and emulate user input? Show exactly what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: @JimB I have added shell script example, How can I do it in golang ?

Comment: I think you'll have to use additional commands. It's not like you can keep an interactive prompt running, you issue a command, you read it's output from stdout, you do whatever logic is necessary in the code to prepare the next command and then run it and continue this process either as a list of statements or in a loop until you have no more commands to run.

Comment: Please provide a runnable example via https://play.golang.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably do something like this which is more native and doesn't involve an external package

```
package main
import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command("ls")
    // redirect the output to terminal
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    cmd.Run()

}
```

Comment: i saw this on redit but if you replace the ls with ftp it doesnt prompt me, it just dies.

Comment: Oh I see. Check out this stack so that you can set stdin  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321437/golang-how-to-execute-command-which-requires-input-from-user

Comment: Seems to work for interactive but doesnt for no interactive like if you compile it and pass in an argument e.g., cmd := exec.Command("ftp --help") It doesnt output anything. any idea?

Comment: @Victor see this article I think this will help tons https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/12/29/shelled-out-commands-in-golang/

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally these sorts of interactive scripting exercises are best done with expect.  May I suggest checking out a [pure Go equivalent](https://github.com/ThomasRooney/gexpect)?

From the readme:

```
child, err := gexpect.Spawn("python")
if err != nil { panic(err) }
child.Expect(">>>")
child.SendLine("print 'Hello World'")
child.Interact()
child.Close()
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that Gexpect has built-in timeout management and an example for ftp specifically at https://github.com/ThomasRooney/gexpect/blob/master/examples/ftp.go

Answer (score 0):

To run any commands which will prompt for user input:

```
cmd := exec.Command("cf", "login")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin

cmd.Run()
```

Answer (score 0):

A command can be "wrapped" using the following complete script, based on [reticentroot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39736673/7069140) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55055100/7069140) regarding obtaining exec command return codes (go 1.12+):

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

var (
    bin = "py"
    args = []string{"-3.8"}
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command(bin, append(args, os.Args[1:]...)...)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    if err := cmd.Run() ; err != nil {
        if exitError, ok := err.(*exec.ExitError); ok {
            os.Exit(exitError.ExitCode())
        }
    }
}
```